# Have any Jedi defied the council to train a padawan?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, jedi-training

Qui-Gon Jinn wanted to train Anakin despite opposition from the Jedi Council.

He even convinced Obi-Wan to train Anakin, and although the council eventually agreed with that decision, at the time, it was also against the council's decision.

Other than Qui-Gon Jinn wanting to train Anakin, **have any other Jedi defied the Jedi Council to train somebody?** Or would have defied the council if circumstances had not prevented them?

The intent of the questions is to ask how often did Jedi defy the council on whom they want to train. If Qui-Gon thought he could defy the council and choose to train Anakin, then perhaps other Jedi had done it and gotten away with it in the past.

Please provide support from canon sources for your answers.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Did Anakin train somebody against the council's orders in the Clone Wars animated series? I have not seen that series.

Comment: @RichS - He trained Ahsoka on the council's explicit instructions.

Comment: @Valorum If Anakin trained Ahsoka as instructed by the council, then that's not what the question is about. I am asking if anybody defied the council to train somebody.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Qui-Gon **would have** defied the council, but he died before he ever got a chance to train Anakin. Therefore, "X did not happen" even though it could have happened. I can modify the question to make it even clearer that I am not asking about Qui-Gon wanting to train Anakin.

Comment: Hmmm.  I don't think it's a matter of whether anyone had "gotten away with it", since it seems clear that Qui-Gon and Obi-Wan were well within their rights, and the most the council could have done about it was to refuse to promote them.  And maybe pay extra close attention to their future expenses claims. :-)  Even so, it obviously isn't an everyday occurrence, they seemed to expect Qui-Gon to fall into line.  An interesting question.  Are Legends answers acceptable?